# How to find several documents at once by querying

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have a list of product IDs in a List[String]. I want to return a List[JsObject] from Mongo, one JsObject for each element in the product List.

I have the following to get just one product:

```
def getIndivProduct(productID: String): Future[List[JsObject]] = {

  val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collectionItems.
      find(Json.obj("product-number" -> productID)).
      cursor[JsObject]

  val futureProductList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()

  futureProductList

}
```

How can I 'feed it' a List of Strings to search and return? With this signature:

```
 def getProductsFromList(productIDs: List[String]): Future[List[JsObject]] = {

    ???

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use $in, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
def getIndivProduct(productIDs: List[String]): Future[List[JsObject]] = {

  val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collectionItems.
      find(Json.obj("product-number" -> Json.obj("$in" -> productIDs))).
      cursor[JsObject]

  val futureProductList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()
  futureProductList
}
```

I've wrote simple helpers to write sophisticated queries, because all that Json -> Json -> Json stuff really annoying.

https://github.com/sh1ng/ReactiveMongo-Queries

Answer (score 0):

You need a transformation function from *List-of-Future-of-List* to *Future-of-List*

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def singleFuture[A](futures: List[Future[List[A]]]): Future[List[A]] = {

    val p = Promise[List[A]]()
    p.success(List.empty[A])

    val f = p.future // a future containing empty list.

    futures.foldRight(f) {
        (fut, accum) =>  // foldRight means accumulator is on right.

        for {
            listAccum <- accum; 
            listA  <- fut  
        }
        yield (listA ::: listAccum)   // List[A] ::: List[A]
    }
}
```

Given this, it is straight forward:

```
def getProductsFromList(productIDs: List[String]): Future[List[JsObject]] = {

    val indivProdList = productIDs.map(getIndivProduct(_))
    singleFuture(indivProdList)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But this still means that I am calling the getIndivProduct() function as many times as there are products in the list to fetch over the wire. The MongoDB is on a different continent so I was hoping there is a way using the ReactiveMongo API to send Mongo a list of products and it would then compile a list of documents and send it back, all in just one call out over the wire.